# Python how to do random numbers

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

So i am building a program that lets me execute different programs. i have a menu and it has 17 different options. The last one is to generate a random number but how do i get the program to generate the number and use that number to input it: heres a sample of my code...

```
import os
import random
print ("""
Press enter to exit
1.)BeamNG Drive 
.....
17.)Random
""")
if answer == "1":
    os.startfile("D:\Games\BeamNG Drive\BeamNG.drive.exe")
    print("Launching BeamNG")
elif answer == "17":
    from random import randint
    print(random.randint(0, 14))
```

Comment: You never request for an input

Comment: You should not need to specify `random` in your last line: `print(randint(0, 14))`

Comment: You can also move `from random import randint` to the top of your program instead of your in your `elif`

Comment: Write exactly what is the problem! See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using recursion. If you put the processing in a function, it can recall itself if the number is 17

```
import os
import random



def choose_program(number)
    if number == "1":
        os.startfile("D:\Games\BeamNG Drive\BeamNG.drive.exe")
        print("Launching BeamNG")
    elif number == "17":
        number = str(random.randint(0, 14))
        print(number)
        choose_program(number)


number = input("""
Press enter to exit
1.)BeamNG Drive 
.....
17.)Random
""")

choose_program(number)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be unaware that one frequent way of handling multiple choices such as this in Python involves the use of a dictionary. Here's another way of solving that problem using that approach.

```
import os
import random

game = {
'1': 'D:\Games\BeamNG Drive\BeamNG.drive.exe',
'2': 'game 2',
'3': 'game 3',
'4': 'game 4',
'5': 'game 5',
'6': 'game 6',
'7': 'game 7',
'8': 'game 8',
'9': 'game 9',
'10': 'game 10',
'11': 'game 11',
'12': 'game 12',
'13': 'game 13',
'14': 'game 14',
'15': 'game 15',
'16': 'game 16',
}

game['17'] = game[str(random.randint(1,16))]

for n in range(1, 17):
    print (n, game[str(n)])
print (17, 'Random choice of one of these')

choice = input()

print (game[choice])
```

The advantage is that the code tends to be more compact and easier to read than a series of `if`, `elif` and `else` statements. In this case just note that the alternative involving `random` has to be declared outside the main definition of the `game` dictionary because it includes a mention of `game` itself, so `game` has to be defined before it can be referred to. In your case, you would need to make a dictionary containing a list, one list item with the name of the item for printing and one list item with the file name to be executed.